# Nuxt - Handle routes at runtime with ssr activated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello there: quick question
I've

- a Nuxt app with the `target: 'server'` in the nuxt.config.js
- an API with an endpoint that give me, for a given path, a template associated ( eg: `/person/maxime` will give me template: `PersonsSingle` )
- a vue component that handles this page ( eg: `_pages/person.vue` )

How can I handle this at runtime ? I guess it's something to do with the middlewares but which one and what is the best strategy here ?

PS: I use this system because two urls with the same structure (eg: `/person/maxime` and `/person/sam` could lead to two completely different templates ). Don't ask why I have to deal with it :/

Comment: Use a structure like `pages/_person` here rather since it will be the person that will be the variable here. Also, you don't really need a middleware here, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70071854/8816585) is pretty much enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```js
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const data = await $axios.$get('...')

  const templateType = data.templateType

  return {
    templateType
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <page-1 v-if="templateType === 'foo'" />

    <page-2 v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```